# I have installed sbt, but still I do not get the REPL

Tags: scala, installation, sbt

I need to install the scala interpreter (aka repl). The official website https://scala-lang.org/download/ gives me instructions on how to install sbt. I have installed sbt, but still do not have the interpreter. What am I missing here? I am supposed to type scala followed by the Enter key.

[Edit] Someone suggested me to type "console" after sbt is running, but I got an error message

```
sbt:slides> console
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/zell/slides/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[error] /Users/zell/slides/examFakeSolution.scala:108:10: not found: value fpinscala
[error]   import fpinscala.monoids.Monoid
[error]          ^
[error] /Users/zell/slides/examFakeSolution.scala:128:45: not found: type Monoid
[error]   def foldBack[A] (l :List[A]) (implicit M :Monoid[A]) :A =
[error]
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have sbt, you have the REPL. You are doing it right, you can run `sbt` and then `console` or directly run `sbt console`

The error is a compilation error. Fix it first and then you'll be able to run the REPL in that folder.

When you run the REPL, sbt tries to compile the project first. So you can also run it in any folder other than the one from the project and it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want start scala REPL inside SBT, type `sbt` firstly, then `console`

To start REPL without installing SBT, download the Scala from official site, add `%SCALA_HOME%/bin` to `PATH` and type `scala` in the terminal.

Comment: type "console" in sbt doesnot seem to work. See my edits above. BTW, you said "download the Scala from official site", did you mean download sbt?

Comment: @zell you should run `sbt` in the root of your project. Firstly, you asked about running REPL in common. But now we're talking about running REPL inside the project directory

Comment: What if I would like to use repl without a specific project? Say I just want to type 2+3 and see the repl returns res0: Int=5

Comment: @zell use the answer

Comment: Could you explain " download the Scala from official site"?  Did you mean sbt or what, as I have already installed sbt.

Comment: @zell if you already have SBT, use it. type `sbt`, then `console`, profit

Comment: Sorry but I copied the error message I got above. I wanted to type "2+3" on the scala console.